# Android: How to save current visible fragment in navigation drawer like gmail app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer with fragments similar to the gmail app. But I am encountering two issues:

1: Suppose I select item x from the nav drawer. The corresponding fragment(fragment x) is displayed with no problem. However, when I change the orientation, the activity is recreated and fragment 1 (default fragment) is displayed ,  even though the navigation drawer shows item x as checked.

2: Again Suppose I select item x. Again the corresponding fragment(fragment x) is displayed with no problem. Now I close the app by pressing the home button and open up 10 other apps. After some time when I re-open my app, the activity is recreated and fragment 1 (default fragment) is displayed, even though the navigation drawer shows item x as checked.

Both the problems are similar and probably require the the same solution. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Manifest, add

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

This will stop the Activity from refreshing on such changes, including the case you mentioned, which is an orientation change.

For the Activity to resume after restoring from a minimised position, override the onPause and onResume methods in the Activity.

> @Override public void onPause() {
>       super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first }
>
> @Override public void onResume() {
>       super.onResume();
>       //Do the things you want to do }

For reference: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: can you please elaborate this further? What should i do on onResume?